# creating custom item in ADMIN_MENU_ORDER

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the custom functionality of `ADMIN_MENU_ORDER`?

I want to do something like so -

```
ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
     ("Content", ("pages.Page", "blog.BlogPost",
        "generic.ThreadedComment", ("Media Library", "fb_browse"),)),
     ("Site", ("sites.Site", "redirects.Redirect", "conf.Setting")),
     ("Users", ("auth.User", "auth.Group",)),
     ("MYAPP", ("View1", "app_view1")),
 )
```

From what I gather I need to use redirects from URLs but *where* and *how* am I doing this?  What I'm assuming is I'm doing this in MYAPP?

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^view1/$', 'View1', name='app_view1'),
)
```

And then generate that in my `views.py`?

```
class View1():
    queryset = model.objects.all().values('fielda', 'fieldb', 'fieldc')

    def get(self):
        return queryset
```

My custom menu items still don't show up.  I'm guessing I need to parse them into a template or return the results in a format that can be consumed by the mezzanine code?  In which case what does that format need to be?

Comment: When you asked "are there any mezzanine working examples where I can see how...", you asked for the community to find you an off-site resource. That's frowned upon on Stack Overflow, and could result in your question being closed. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: @jww sorry I should have rephrased the question.

Comment: No need to apologize. Click *Edit* and rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pasted an example right there in your question:

`("Media Library", "fb_browse")`

From the docs: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/admin-customization.html#custom-items

*It is possible to inject custom navigation items into the
ADMIN_MENU_ORDER setting by specifying an item using a two item
sequence, the first item containing the title and second containing
the named urlpattern that resolves to the url to be used.*

There's no need for redirects. You just need to use the urlpattern names. Your urlpatterns weren't named, they'd look like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^view1/$', 'view1', name='my_view1'),
    url(r'^view2/$', 'view2', name='my_view2'),
)
```

Then:

```
ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
    ...
    ("MYAPP", (("First", "my_view1"), ("Second", "my_view2"))),
)
```

Comment: I think I understand so I'm going to give this a shot now and see if it works.

Comment: I've created the urlpatterns, updated my settings.py and but how do I generate the views.py to allow it to use the same formatting as exists within the existing admin menus?  Do I need to return the queryset as a csv, is there a template I should be generating it into?  The documentation doesn't seem to be explaining any of this.  I'm updating my question

Comment: Thanks this worked!  I forgot one major point that was missing in the root urls.py which was to include the myapp.urls!  As soon as I dumped that in the menu item appeared!

Comment: The Mezzanine documentation doesn't cover how to write views since that's just a general Django topic and much better covered by its own documentation.